# Get stream context defaults in a human-readable format

Tags: php, stream

I set the stream context default options using PHP's [stream_context_set_default()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.stream-context-set-default.phpa) function.

```
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
        )
    )
);
```

The function [stream_context_set_default()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.stream-context-get-default.php) returns the defaults as the default resource. Is there a way to fetch the defaults as string, array or something else human-readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function [stream_context_get_options()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-get-options.php) can be used to fetch the options array from a given context.

```
    $expectedStreamContextOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
        )
    );

    $defaultStreamContext = stream_context_get_default();
    $defaultStreamContextOptions = stream_context_get_options($defaultStreamContext);
```

Thanks to Paul Crovella for his comment.